# Validating field's presence fails even though the field is not blank

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, activerecord

I'm trying to fill out an array with values from checkboxes. It works just fine when creating a record, but fails validation when editing. The params look right, which is what really confuses me:

```
"record"=>{... "type_array"=>["accounting"], ...}
```

It looks the same as the params from creating a new record. The fields in `New.html.erb` and `Edit.html.erb` also use the same markup.

**Edit.html.erb**

```
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :type_array, "What type of record?" %><br />
  <% ["accounting", "agriculture", "automotive"].each do |type| %>
    <%= check_box_tag 'record[type_array][]', type, (true if @record.type_list.include? type),
                      :id => type %>
    <%= label_tag type, type.titleize, :class => type %><br />
  <% end %>
</div>
```

**Parts of Record.rb**

```
validates :type_array, :presence => true
attr_accessor :type_array
attr_accessible :type_array
before_validation :set_type_list

private

def set_type_list
  self.type_list = type_array.join ',' if type_array.present?
end
```

Am I missing something? When I remove the `type_array` validation and fill out the form, it acts like type_array is empty. Somewhere along the line, it must be lost or something.

I appreciate any help.

(Sidenote: if anyone has a better way to do the list of checkboxes, let me know)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Delete the line `attr_accessor :type_array`.

This creates accessor methods to a new instance variable, not to the model attribute `type_array`, which means that `@record.type_array` now refers to that instance variable instead of the attribute.

You almost never use `attr_accessor` or it's siblings `attr_reader` and `attr_writer` in Rails because you want to deal with model attributes, not instance variables.

**Edit:** You're using `type_array` as a virtual attribute.

```
class Record < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :type_array, :presence => true
  attr_accessible :type_array

  def type_array=(val)
    self.type_list = val.join ','
  end

  def type_array
    self.type_list.split ','
  end

  def type_array_before_type_cast
    type_array
  end
end
```

For the reason why you need that last function definition, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3916849/rails-validating-virtual-attributes).

Comment: I don't have a type_array column in the records table, though, so don't I need to include the attr_accessor to kind of "create" it? Basically, I'm using the checkboxes to populate an array (type_array) and then processing it in the model and saving it as type_list. When I remove the attr_accessor, it throws an `undefined local variable or method `type_array'` exception. (I edited the model code with the type_list part.)

Comment: Ah, you're using it as a virtual attribute. I will edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: Cool, I never would have thought of splitting it up like that. It still doesn't work when editing the record, though. It doesn't throw any validation errors, so that's good. It still works when creating a new record, so that's also good. The params still look right (`"type_array"=>["construction", "healthcare", "nonprofits"]`). What's confusing me to no end is that the params look fine and how creating a new record works perfectly. Thanks for the help so far.

Comment: Nothing. It saves the record without raising anything but type_list does not change. I check a few more checkboxes, save the record, but type_list pretends like nothing happened. If it matters, I'm doing this to set tags with acts_as_taggable_one. The same method works for another model, which makes this odd.

Comment: Try updating a record from the console and see if that works. This is the standard way of doing virtual attributes and the fact that creating a record works fine points to the problem being somewhere else in the edit action.

Comment: In the console, editing a record through `record.update_attributes` doesn't work. Doing `record.type_list = ["nonprofits", "healthcare", "services"]` and saving the record does. Does that clear anything up?

Comment: @Nathan let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2194/discussion-between-luke-and-nathan)

Comment: Hey, after fixing a somewhat embarrassing mistake in the controller, your fixes worked. Thanks a bunch for helping me out with it.